# ASP.NET Gridview button onclick not firing

Tags: asp.net

Hi all I have a simpe ASP button inside a grid. But the onclick event doesn't seem to fire. Where did I go wrong?

Here's the first line of my aspx page.

```
<%@ Page Title="Trainer Data" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeFile="TrainerData.aspx.vb" Inherits="TrainerData"%>
```

And the button inside my gridview..

```
<asp:GridView ID ="gvExecSummary" runat="server" CssClass="gridview" AllowSorting="false" AllowPaging="false" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="98%" >
<RowStyle Height="22px" />
<AlternatingRowStyle Height="22px" CssClass="bg" BackColor="LightGray"/>
<HeaderStyle Height="22px" BackColor="#4b6c9e" Font-Bold="true"/>
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField  HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="5%" HeaderText="Action">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Button ID="btnExecutiveGenerate" runat="server" Text="Generate"     OnClientClick="btnExecutiveGenerate_Click" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

P.S. I tried even onclick but it doesn't work either.

EDIT: My code for server side.

```
Protected Sub btnExecutiveGenerate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim gvrow As GridViewRow = CType(CType(sender, Control).Parent.Parent, GridViewRow)
    Dim lblSchoolId As System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label = gvrow.FindControl("lblSchoolMasterID")
    Dim lblFacultyId As System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label = gvrow.FindControl("lblFacultyMasterID")
    Dim btnExecutiveGenerate As System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button = gvrow.FindControl("btnExecutiveGenerate")

    PDF_Creation_Executive(Val(lblSchoolId.Text), Val(lblFacultyId.Text))

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have the code for **btnExecutiveGenerate_Click**? If so, could you post it here too?

Comment: Hi, pl check my edit.

Comment: @Aishvarya how you load data to gridview ? are you doing it page load method? can you please update with that code?

Comment: Hi, I load the grid on selected index changed of a dropwdown and here is the code..    Dim dbl As New vtisDAL.vtisDALDataContext
        Dim dsGetFacDtls = From dF In dbl.usp_GetFacultyDetails(0).AsQueryable Where dF.SchoolMasterID = Val(CboSubSchoolSel.SelectedValue) Select dF Order By dF.SchoolID, dF.FacultyID
        gvExecSummary.DataSource = dsGetFacDtls
        gvExecSummary.DataBind()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Command Argumnet,

```
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:Button ID="AddButton" runat="server" 
  CommandName="AddToCart" 
  CommandArgument="<%# CType(Container,GridViewRow).RowIndex %>"
  Text="Add to Cart" />
   </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

add code page side

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, _ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs)
 If (e.CommandName = "AddToCart") Then
  ' Retrieve the row index stored in the CommandArgument property.
  Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)

  ' Retrieve the row that contains the button 
  ' from the Rows collection.
  Dim row As GridViewRow = GridView1.Rows(index)

  ' Add code here to add the item to the shopping cart.

 End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the button click event of Gridview in `RowCommand` event

**NOTE:** Please see the `CommandName` & `CommandArgument` properties added to the button.

```
<asp:GridView ID ="gvExecSummary" runat="server" CssClass="gridview" AllowSorting="false" AllowPaging="false" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="98%" >
<RowStyle Height="22px" OnRowCommand="gvExecSummary_RowCommand"  />
<AlternatingRowStyle Height="22px" CssClass="bg" BackColor="LightGray"/>
<HeaderStyle Height="22px" BackColor="#4b6c9e" Font-Bold="true"/>
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField  HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="5%" HeaderText="Action">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Button ID="btnExecutiveGenerate" runat="server" Text="Generate"   CommandName="GenerateExecutive" CommandArgument="<%#((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex %>"  />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And and RowCommand event will be..

```
protected void gvExecSummary_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e) 
{ 
      if (e.CommandName == "GenerateExecutive") 
      {
          // button click code goes here
      }
}
```

Comment: My "e" is of type GridViewRowEventArgs so I am not able to access CommandName property.

Comment: @Aishvarya - Could you pleae elaborate? The EventArgs on the handler of GridView _OnRowCommand_ HAS to be of type _GridViewCommandEventArgs_ . And this would have the _CommandName_ and _CommandArgument_ properties available.

Comment: I tried using this. Think the code is bewitched, does not work at all.

Comment: As you see, this is C# code. I have tried this before posting it. Could you please share what error you get?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36523/discussion-between-prash-and-aishvarya)

Answer (score 0):

change `OnClientClick` event  to  `OnClick`  if `btnExecutiveGenerate_Click` is vb.net event handler

```
<asp:Button ID="btnExecutiveGenerate" runat="server" Text="Generate"    
 OnClick="btnExecutiveGenerate_Click"/>
```

`OnClientClick` event use to execute client-side script, if you have given `OnClientClick` event with `OnClick` event, then if `OnClientClick` return `true` only it will call `OnClick` event.

so make sure you are returning true or false from `OnClientClick` event if you using it.

note that if you are loading data in page laod, do as below

```
Sub Page_Load
    If Not IsPostBack
        LoadGridViewData()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: He just said > P.S. I tried even onclick but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

This may help someone, but I was experiencing edit buttons not firing the event within rows (and not footer).
The cause was a gridview containing a label, which had the same ID as one elsewhere on the page.
Seemingly this did not cause problems for the footer row, which did not contain any such labels. 
I hope this helps someone.